# Puppeteer - How to Get Length of Tags with XPath?

Tags: javascript, xpath, puppeteer

I am having some trouble using Puppeteer (Version 1.3).

I'm trying to run this function:

```
async function func(page, selector, value)
{
  let xPath = "//" + selector + "[contains(text(), " + value + ")]";
  let linkHandlers = await page.$x(xPath);
  if (linkHandlers.length > 0)
  {
     await linkHandlers[0].click();
  }
  else 
  {
    console.log("FAILED");
  }
}
```

If I try to run the function for the first time with `selector = 'div'`, it works well.

But, when I try to run it again with a selector that doesn't appear in my code, I receive that `linkHandlers.length = 149`.

How do I get the actual `linkHandlers.length` only for selectors that exist in my code?

Comment: What arguments did you provide the second time? Is it also possible to provide a minimal page example?

Comment: I'm providing those variables:                                                                            async function func(page, 'span', 'pppppppppppppppppppppp');

Answer (score 0):

Before we begin, make sure that you are passing a valid XPath `selector` to your function, rather than a CSS selector.

For example, if you are wanting to select an element with `id="example"`, then your XPath selector should be:

```
*[@id="example"]
```

Additionally, you need to make sure that your `value` is enclosed in quotation marks for the XPath selector to be interpreted properly.

Your `xPath` string should be formatted like this:

```
let xPath = `//${selector}[contains(text(), '${value}')]`;
```